# Save data in html tag attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How save some data as html tag atribute? For example, given data `asd/45.33/blah`, I need save this data in html and after using jquery get this data so:

```
 $("#my_tag").attr("special_attribute");
```

its possible?

Comment: You can use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Did you *try*  it before asking? What happened?

Comment: Too much redundancy in the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using custom attributes makes your document invalid, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attributes and for getting/setting values using jQuery, you can use `data` method, for example if you have a data attribute called `data-special` you can get the value of it in this way:

```
var value = $("#my_tag").data("special");
```

and set/change the value in this way:

```
$("#my_tag").data("special", "value");
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use it with jQuery then a better way to do it is to use `data-` attibutes.

Declaring a html tag will look like:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-url="asd/45.33/blah"></div>
```

Using data is as simple as:

```
var url = $('#myDiv').data('url')
```

More about [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Question about [attr vs data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr).

Answer (score 0):

USE `attr()` it is used for getting the value as well as for setting the attribute value.

```
$("#my_tag").attr("special_attribute",'asd/45.33/blah');
```

Details http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. However it won't validate.

Comment: It will validate in HTML5 with the data attribute http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I think you should use an hidden field for this purpose:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_tag" />
```

and then access it via jquery :

```
$("#my_tag").attr("value", "myvalue");
$("#my_tag").attr("value");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save value in html element as :

```
$("htmlelement").data("key","value");
```

in your case it would be :

```
$("#my_tag").data("special_attribute","asd/45.33/blah");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var html = "<p>HTML</p>";
$("#my_tag").attr("special_attribute", function() {
    return html;
});
```

Now retrieve it with:

```
var s = $("#my_tag").attr("special_attribute");
alert(s)
```

Comment: why use function when you can simply assign a variable?

Comment: @AspiringAqib I know a lot of different people have told you already but at SO, we appreciate when there's a meaning behind the code you submit. If you can't answer the "why" question, perhaps it doesn't need to be there.